# How to obtain more brightness levels using Fn+keys in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, brightness

When using keyboard's keys to adjust brightness I'm only getting 10 values (levels) of screen brightness. Meanwhile using Xfce plugin for brightness, I can fine-tune brightness.

However I want a highly adjustable brightness level.

Is there any way to change brightness level of adjustment to "finer steps" (let's say 30 steps) using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> in Xfce ?

Comment: What distribution are you using? What video card?

Comment: distro is arch and card is intel

Comment: What exact model of video card?

Answer (score 1):

Has this actually been answered yet?  I just found a way to do this, albeit by using the `<super>` key instead of `<functions>`.  Please note, this also works perfectly for **Peppermint Linux** as well.  I know this because it's what I use and love.  Since it's a combination of XFCE and LXDE, I'm positive it'll work for both DEs.

First, you absolutely need to install the `Light` package available on GitHub here:
https://github.com/haikarainen/light
(If you're using Arch, it's available in the AUR as `light` or `light-git`.)

Once that's completed go into your keyboard settings and make new keyboard shortcuts for the following commands and shortcuts.  Now just because I have selected the shortcuts that I did, does not mean anything.  If you want to use something else, go for it.  I opted to use the  key because I could not get my XFCE to recognize that I was holding the  button while trying to set the shortcut.  You might have better luck.

I'm going to use this format for the shortcut and command:

```
Shortcut A  |  Command A
Shortcut B  |  Command B
    etc.    |    etc.
```

I'm also going to leave out the `<___>` from "super" because I don't feel it's necessary to keep typing those characters each time.  You'll know what I mean when I type "super", right?

(Please note, that the capitalization does seem to matter.  "Up" will work in a shortcut; meanwhile "up" will not._

The commands I'm going to use are "`light -A 5`" and "`light -U 5`".  They translate to "Brightness Up by 5" and "Brightness Lower by 5".  That gives you a total of 20 steps of brightness to work with.  If you want to use a different number, go for it.  I would suggest you stay away from numbers smaller than 5, though.  I am also going to use "`light -S 100`" and "`light -S 5`".  They translate to "Set Brightness to Max" and "Set Brightness to Min".

Anyway, here's the shortcut and commands:

```
super + Up    |  light -A 5
super + Down  |  light -U 5

super + shift + .  |  light -S 100
super + shift + ,  |  light -S 5
         OR
super + >  |  light -S 100
super + <  |  light -S 5
```

Feel free to add any other shortcuts you feel you'd use frequently!

Please let me know if this works for you!  I'll definitely appreciate any feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an open feature request for this here:

https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12062

It is not too hard to make the changes and recompile xfce4-power-manager by yourself from the source. My specific version was here:

http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/4.10/src/xfce4-power-manager-1.2.0.tar.bz2

Unpack it, cd to the directory, type `./configure` at the prompt and get the missing packages (e.g. `sudo apt-get install xfce4-panel-dev`) then `./configure` again.

Eventually it will be happy. Then type `make`. If it's still happy then type `make install` and reboot. Voila, you've got more brightness levels.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange (Unix & Linux).  As I'm sure you know, if you type `steak`, the computer (generally) doesn't execute `stake`.  So, do you by any chance mean "type `./configure`" and "then `./config` *again*"?  Or do you mean `./configure` both times?